# jQuery cookies retuning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, click

I am setting value in cookies with jQuery on click event of an anchor tag and it returns correct value before page load but after page load it return different value in alert box. Here is my code.

```
jQuery('.menu li a').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  jQuery.cookie('myCookie', this.id);
  alert(jQuery.cookie('myCookie'));
});
```

Here in this alert box I am getting correct value but after page load when again I tried to get its value it is returning different value.

```
alert(jQuery.cookie('myCookie'));
```

How I can get correct value even after page load. Your help will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: It's going to be almost impossible for us to solve this problem without seeing a working example of it. Your code in isolation seems fine.

Comment: Can i share a link of my site here?
So in this way you will be able to see live example of it.

Comment: Sure, although that's not really helpful. An example in a snippet in the question or a http://jsfiddle.net would be better

Comment: This is a link of my site, you can see its output here and i am also trying to code this in jsfiddle.net 
https://justgetoutoftown.com/tax/

Comment: Sorry if i have done any thing wrong because i have coded first time in jsfiddle. You can see my code here and here it is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/us7jLhx9/10/

Comment: I could not understand why it is not working for me.

Comment: This is working for me. Do you have cookies enabled in your browser? You can go into your browser (under Application tab in chrome) and view your cookies. After clicking the links you have to refresh the tab but then you can see that your cookie is set and for me when i reloaded the page is alerted the cookie.

Comment: @CodyFortenberry thank you for your time but cookies are enabled in my browser and i am getting correct value from cookies before page load but after page load i am getting different value. I have already test this in different browser without any luck.

Comment: Its working for me in both the jsfiddle and your website. The only thing is that your are removing the cookie on page load so it will not work if you reload the page again without setting a new cookie  but that may be your intention.